# подключение псевдоклассов к alt title img в vue.js

Tags: vue.js, изображения

jquery.js

```
$('img').each(function () {
  $(this).after($('<span>').html($(this).attr('alt')));
})

=
vue.js
.....?
```

Comment: Напишите что вы хотите сделать этим кодом

Comment: да. чтоб я так жил...... получилось: хоть атрибуты, хоть теги